# Attribute error : module "pytest" has no attribute "hookimpl"

Tags: python-3.x

I have installed python 3.8.3 in windows 8/64 bit.. I need to start with pytest...path has been set properly... In Pycharm I am getting

```
Attribute error : module "pytest" has no attribute "hookimpl"
```

All the plugins installed as per the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pytest` doesn't supports Python 3.8 yet.
Supported versions for Pytest

- Python 3.5
- Python 3.6
- Python 3.7
- PyPy3

Create a new virtualenv in Pycharm with these versions. If you don't know how here is a link for you.
[Pycharm Configuring Python Interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add_new_project_interpreter)

Also if you are interested you can find more info about [Pytest Installation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/5.4.3/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be an issue with a [Magic String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string) here. Make sure you dont have any file named identically to any internal python code. I changed my package name from 'pytest' to 'pytestdemo' and this error was resolved.

Comment: This has worked on my end as well. `pytest` seems to be a taken keyword to be used as just a folder name

Answer (score -2):

Check your pytest project/package name, it should not start with 'Test'. I got same issue when project/package name was "Test". Changing the project/package name solved the issue.